# Remove comma from last array value

Tags: php, arrays

**PHP**

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
$images = $meta['img1'][0];    // urls separated with comma
$images = explode(',', $images);
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '{image : '.$image.', title : "Credit: x"},'; 
};
```

**Output**:

```
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/1.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'},
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/2.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'},
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/3.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'},
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/4.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'}, // last comma, just after }
```

I would like to remove the last commented comma in output.

This is exactly what I'm trying to get:

**Desired output**:

```
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/1.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'},
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/2.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'},
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/3.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'},
{image : 'http://localhost/slideshow/4.jpg', title : 'Credit: x'}
```

Comment: How about using the build in PHP functions to generate valid JSON? (json_encode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of options:

```
// Using rtrim
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
$images = $meta['img1'][0];    // urls separated with comma
$images = explode(',', $images);
$string = '';
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $string .= '{image : '.$image.', title : "Credit: x"},'; 
};
$string = rtrim($string, ',');
echo $string;

// Using substring
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
$images = $meta['img1'][0];    // urls separated with comma
$images = explode(',', $images);
$string = '';
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $string .= '{image : '.$image.', title : "Credit: x"},'; 
};
$string = substr($string, 0, -1);
echo $string;

// Using implode
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
$images = $meta['img1'][0];    // urls separated with comma
$images = explode(',', $images);
$stringElements = array();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    stringElements[] = '{image : '.$image.', title : "Credit: x"}'; 
};

$string =  implode(',', $stringElements);
echo $string;
```

Also consider using a more efficient way to create JSON strings: [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 2):

You can buffer output into variable and solve this way:

```
echo rtrim($bufferedData, ',');
```

But as I can see, it's better for you to use [json functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Answer (score 2):

So all your code is about creating JSON from your data. That will be:

```
$data   = 'http://localhost/slideshow/1.jpg,http://localhost/slideshow/2.jpg,http://localhost/slideshow/3.jpg';
$credit = 'x';
$result = json_encode(array_map(function($image) use ($credit)
{
   return ['image'=>$image, 'Credit'=>$credit];
}, explode(',', $data)));
//var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this using rtrim()

```
$images = 'image1.png,image2.png,image3.png';
$ex = explode(',', $images);
foreach ($ex as $image) {
    $image_string .= "{'image' : '{$image}', 'title' : 'Credit: x'},"; 
}

print rtrim($image_string, ',');
```

Above returns below

```
{'image' : 'image1.png', 'title' : 'Credit: x'},
{'image' : 'image2.png', 'title' : 'Credit: x'},
{'image' : 'image3.png', 'title' : 'Credit: x'}
```